# Create custom error with stack trace

Tags: go, stack-trace, embedding

I'm trying to use [go-errors](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-errors/errors) to include stack traces with errors I generate. I have a custom `HttpError` type that I also want to include stack traces. My initial thought was to do this with an embed, but I can't seem to embed it since the name of the class (`Error`) is the same as the name of one of the methods.

```
package netutil

import (
  "github.com/go-errors/errors"
)

type HttpError struct {
  status int
  *errors.Error
}

func (h *HttpError) Error() string {
  return "Failed"
}

func NewHttpError(status int, message string) *HttpError {
  return &HttpError{
    status,
    errors.New(message),
  }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
tmp_error.go:12: type HttpError has both field and method named Error
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just name this inner error with something appropriate like `inner-error` or `stack-trace`?

```
type HttpError struct {
  status int
  StackTace *errors.Error
}
```

Seems to be fairly common practice in classes used for error handling in other languages/frameworks like .NET and Java.

Another option would be to concatenate your custom message with the inner error using `fmt.Sprintf` at the time you create the error, keeping it all as one.

`errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("This proprietary error happened! Stack trace: %s", message))`;

If you did that you wouldn't implement `func (h *HttpError) Error()` since you'd be relying on the embedded error for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked, Go errors patterns have evolved quite a bit. There is now a [standard way of wrapping errors into new errors](https://pkg.go.dev/errors) with potentially additional information. This is then used by packages like [`gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors`](https://gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors) (disclaimer: I am its maintainer) to add additional information, e.g., stack traces, or structured details.

So your example could then look like:

```golang
package netutil

import (
  "gitlab.com/tozd/go/errors"
)

type HttpError struct {
  status int
}

func (h *HttpError) Error() string {
  return "Failed"
}

func NewHttpError(status int, message string) error {
  return errors.WithMessage(&HttpError{status}, message)
}
```

`errors.WithMessage` prepends the `message` to the error message of the `HttpError` error and records a stack trace (if the error does not already have it, which `HttpError` does not). You can format then the error to get the stack trace:

```golang
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
```